# Is there a way to avoid code repetition in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm currently learning d3 and I'm in the process of creating an SVG that has four rectangles within it all organized in a horizontal line. They all have the same size, height, and color. There is a lot of redundancy in making each `rect` object and I was wondering if there was a way to optimize it.

I was wondering if there was a way to make a `rect` object and set almost all of the attributes I need (height, width, y-position, fill color) and then go in and create four copies of each rectangle and just set the x-position for whatever I wanted.
I haven't really coded much with JS and am used to Java so some of the object creation syntax and procedure is unfamiliar to me.

```
var smallBoxMargin = {top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20};
    var boxH = 150;
    var smallBoxDim = {width: (w/4)-smallBoxMargin.left-smallBoxMargin.right, height: boxH-smallBoxMargin.top-smallBoxMargin.bottom}
    var boxSvg = d3.select("#boxDiv")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("height",boxH)
      .attr("width",w);
    var boxMidpoint = w/2;
    boxSvg.append("rect") //inner left box
      .attr("class","smallBox")
      .attr("width",smallBoxDim.width)
      .attr("height",smallBoxDim.height)
      .attr("fill",eteOrange)
      .attr("x", boxMidpoint - smallBoxDim.width - smallBoxMargin.right)
      .attr("y", smallBoxMargin.top) 
    boxSvg.append("rect") //inner right box
      .attr("class","smallBox")
      .attr("width",smallBoxDim.width)
      .attr("height",smallBoxDim.height)
      .attr("fill",eteOrange)
      .attr("x", boxMidpoint+smallBoxMargin.left)
      .attr("y", smallBoxMargin.top)
    boxSvg.append("rect") //outer left box
      .attr("class","smallBox")
      .attr("width",smallBoxDim.width)
      .attr("height",smallBoxDim.height)
      .attr("fill",eteOrange)
      .attr("x", boxMidpoint-2*smallBoxDim.width - 2*smallBoxMargin.right-smallBoxMargin.left)
      .attr("y", smallBoxMargin.top)
    boxSvg.append("rect") //outer right box
      .attr("class","smallBox")
      .attr("width",smallBoxDim.width)
      .attr("height",smallBoxDim.height)
      .attr("fill",eteOrange)
      .attr("x", boxMidpoint+smallBoxDim.width+2*smallBoxMargin.left+smallBoxMargin.right)
      .attr("y", smallBoxMargin.top)
```

The code above works, it is just very redundant in the attributes for class, width, height, fill, and y. Each `boxSvg.append("rect")` is the start of a new rectangle element.
`smallBoxDim` has the dimensions of the smaller boxes, `smallBoxMargin` has the margins for the smaller boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an **enter selection**!

D3 stands for ***D***ata-**D**riven **D**ocuments (that is, DDD or D3). If you are not using the data-binding capabilities of D3 you're **missing the whole point** of using D3! The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57189501/5768908), despite well intentioned, also completely ignores that.

Long story short, in your rectangles only the `x` position varies. Therefore, in your case, this is the data (which can be substantially simplified, but I digress) you need, an array with all those positions:

```
var data = [boxMidpoint - smallBoxDim.width - smallBoxMargin.right, boxMidpoint + smallBoxMargin.left, 
    boxMidpoint - 2 * smallBoxDim.width - 2 * smallBoxMargin.right - smallBoxMargin.left, 
    boxMidpoint + smallBoxDim.width + 2 * smallBoxMargin.left + smallBoxMargin.right
];
```

With that data array in hand, this is the enter selection:

```
var rects = boxSvg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "smallBox")
  .attr("width", smallBoxDim.width)
  .attr("height", smallBoxDim.height)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .attr("y", smallBoxMargin.top);
```

And that's all you need for not repeating the code again and again and again...

Here is the demo:

```js
var smallBoxMargin = {top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20};
var boxH = 150;
var w = 400;
var smallBoxDim = {
  width: (w / 4) - smallBoxMargin.left - smallBoxMargin.right,
  height: boxH - smallBoxMargin.top - smallBoxMargin.bottom
};
var boxSvg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", boxH)
  .attr("width", w);
var boxMidpoint = w / 2;
var data = [boxMidpoint - smallBoxDim.width - smallBoxMargin.right, boxMidpoint + smallBoxMargin.left, boxMidpoint - 2 * smallBoxDim.width - 2 * smallBoxMargin.right - smallBoxMargin.left, boxMidpoint + smallBoxDim.width + 2 * smallBoxMargin.left + smallBoxMargin.right];

var rects = boxSvg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "smallBox")
  .attr("width", smallBoxDim.width)
  .attr("height", smallBoxDim.height)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d
  })
  .attr("y", smallBoxMargin.top);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, can I ask how you would have simplified the data? Is it just a matter of using so many variables to determine the x-values?

Comment: Look for *"band scale"* in D3 docs and you'll see how easy it is.

Answer (score -1):

Make it a function! It can take in the element you want to append to and all of the attributes you want to set. Something like this:

```
function makeSmallBox(parent, width, height, fill, x, y) {
       parent.append("rect")
          .attr("class","smallBox")
          .attr("width",width)
          .attr("height",height)
          .attr("fill",fill)
          .attr("x", x)
          .attr("y", y);
}
```

That way, to make your inner left box, you can do something like this:

```
makeSmallBox(boxSvg, smallBoxDim.width, smallBoxDim.height, eteOrange, (boxMidpoint - smallBoxDim.width - smallBoxMargin.right), smallBoxMargin.top)
```

Or, if that's too many arguments for your taste, you can have the function take in an object of options:

```
function makeSmallBox(parent, options) {
       parent.append("rect")
          .attr("class","smallBox")
          .attr("width",options.width)
          .attr("height",options.height)
          .attr("fill",options.fill)
          .attr("x", options.x)
          .attr("y", options.y);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
const topLeftOptions = {
    width: smallBoxDim.width,
    height: smallBoxDim.height,
    fill: eteOrange,
    x:(boxMidpoint - smallBoxDim.width - smallBoxMargin.right), 
    y: smallBoxMargin.top
}
makeSmallBox(boxSvg, topLeftOptions);
```

Then you can call the function four times, once for each rectangle. If you want to make it even cleaner, put those four `options` objects in an array, and [loop over it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), calling the function once each iteration:

```
// assume optionsArray contains all four objects. I don't really want to type them all out
optionsArray.forEach((el) => makeSmallBox(boxSvg, topLeftOptions));
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow up question just because I'm curious, could I make a function that itself produces functions? Would that even be useful?

Comment: You can 100% make a function that returns functions. JavaScript has [first-order functions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/discover-the-power-of-first-class-functions-fd0d7b599b69/), which means you can do things like pass functions as arguments, store them in an array, or return them from functions. You can read more about functions returning functions [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions).